# White space appears when using margin-top

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to use margin-top push a container down relative to its parent container. However, when trying to do so, a white gap is appearing between the parent div and the preceeding div (see screenshots). I am wondering if anyone has a solution[image] for this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: in order to attract the best answers, please create an example that boils the problem down to its simplest form, then post that code here. being able to reproduce the problem is an important step in finding a solution.

Comment: use `reset.css` it looks like you `tag` for `Hero Message` is giving the `margin`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use padding, not margin if the issue is that the background isn't getting filled in. This applies to the parent div, not the child:

http://jsfiddle.net/tmd4thpa/

```
.container {
  background: purple;
  padding:20px;
}
.div {
  height:500px;
  background: red;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="div"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly. After reading your answer it was kind of a "DUH!" moment for me. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to margin collapse. If you add a very small top padding to the container this doesn't happen since they are then separated. Not sure about the underlying mechanism of margin collapse here.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).